# Books on experimental methods, fluid mechanics related

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, aerodynamics, flow

I need some good books on experimental methods, requirements are:

1. Fluid mechanics related;
2. Thermal, multi-phase etc. topics should be covered;
3. Traditional methods are good, but it would be greater if modern techniques are covered;
4. [optional] aerodynamics;

Any recommendations on some four/five star books?